# Mongo kubernetes securing

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, 3d-secure

I'm trying to create username/password for my mongodb on kubernetes. But seems MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME/PASSWORD is not work or work incorrect as I cannot login with this credentials:

```
   apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongotest
spec:
  revisionHistoryLimit: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongotest 
  replicas: 1
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongotest
    spec:
      hostname: mongotest
      containers:
      - name: mongotest
        image: mongo
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        restartPolicy: Always
        env:
          - name: "MONGO_DATA_DIR"
            value: "/data/db"
          - name: "MONGO_LOG_DIR"
            value: "/data/logs"  
          - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
            value: test
          - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
            value: test
          - name: MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE
            value: admin
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command:
              - /bin/sh
              - -c
              - >
                mongo --eval 'db.auth('test', 'test');db = db.getSiblingDB("admin"); db.createUser({ user: "admin", pwd: "test", roles: [{ role: "root", db: "admin" }]});'
        ports:
        - name: port27017
          containerPort: 27017
```

Comment: can you provide more information? what error are you getting? does your `lifecycle` pass?

Comment: it shows connection refused, seems username/pass is not recognized.

Comment: yes. i am seeing same issue. however if i remove lifecycle i can login with username: test and password: test

Comment: yes, you are right, removing lifecycle works. It created admin DB with username/pass.
How to have one username/pass for whole mongo, which allows to create any DB?

Comment: The `test` user that is created with provided username/password has role `root` . so it is allowed to create any database. You can check available users and their role using `show users` command after login into the database.

Read `Environment Variables` part here https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/.

Comment: However, you shouldn't provide username, password as environment variable directly. Then anybody who can view the yaml will able to view your credential. Create a secret with this credential and then use that secret in environment variable. You will find example here https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables.

Answer (score 1):

Gathering all the information from the comments:
The reason why the authentication was failing was due to unrecognized username/password. 
Removing lifecycle section works as it disables authentication and the user is able to reach the MongoDB and create new users.

> If you do not provide these two variables or do not set the --auth
>   flag with your own custom user setup, then MongoDB will not require
>   authentication. For more details about the functionality described
>   here, please see the sections in the official documentation which
>   describe authentication and authorization in more detail.

Following MongoDB [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authentication/):

> Use the mongo command-line authentication options (--username,
>   --password, and --authenticationDatabase) when connecting to the mongod or mongos instance, or
>
> Connect first to the mongod or mongos instance, and then run the
>   authenticate command or the db.auth() method against the
>   authentication database.

So in case of docker you could run something like:

`docker run -d --name some-mongo -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=mongoadmin -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret mongo`

In Kubernetes as it has different character so you could either make containers to run specific commands in the configuration yaml:
for example:
`containers:
  - image: mongo
    name: mongoadmin
    command: ["mongo", "--auth"]`

Although the safest way is to use secrets, because passing username and password in environment variables is not the best practice. 
You can find more about secrets in the official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables). And more from Docker perspective in Docker Secrets chapter [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/).